# Bootstrap toggle button is not working (does not load event listeners in spite bootstrap.js loaded into source files)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to rebuild the aspnetcore mvc-template from a regular aspnetcore console app. Right now I'm on the front end part and I've written the `_Layout.cshtml`-file. When I run the app, the navbar-button (which shows on smaller screens) won't work

*this a functioning example of the navbar-button I'm talking about*

[image]

When I write the code it won't work. It sits there beautiful and non-responsive.

*stays like this when I click it*
[image]

Now the button-tag is identical for both:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

The tag that should show is identical for both:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

The script-tag for bootstrap.js is identical for both:

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

When I inspect the button in the working example and check `Event listeners` I see a whole bunch of event-listerners, all of them calling the `bootstrap.js` file:

[image]

When inspecting the button in my own broken code I see no event listeners:

[image]

This makes me think that the bootstrap.js hasn't loaded in my broken code, but then I look on the sources tab:

[image]

And bootstrap.js is there, clearly loaded and everything? What could be the thing causing this problem?

Comment: Do you have the correct version of jQuery loaded in your code?

Comment: Oh my god thank you! I did have the correct version of jQuery loaded but the script-tags were loaded in reverse order in my code (first bootstrap.js then jquery.js). When I switched the order it started working (switched back, stopped working, so definitely that). Do you know why this is so?

Comment: Bootstrap is dependent on jQuery for certain things, so if the jQuery doesn't load first, Bootstrap may not react how it's supposed to.

Comment: I'm gonna write up an answer so anyone else who has the same problem will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap relies on jQuery for certain functions, so jQuery must be loaded before the `bootstrap.js` file.  If you have multiple script files, it's good practice to check for dependencies and make sure any required files are loaded first.  (Speaking from experience!)